# How to add new instance of combo box everytime a button is clicked in c# programatically

Tags: c#, winforms, combobox

I would like to create a c# windows form where if a button 'Add combobox' is clicked, the system will create 1 instance of 'combobox' every click.

The positions of each instance will be plus 5px longitude below each other.

If possible kindly populate too the new instance with some fix values.

Answer (score 2):

You can do something like this on button click (comments are in code):

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    //create new combo
    ComboBox cbo = new ComboBox();
    //fill it with values
    cbo.Items.Add("value1");
    cbo.Items.Add("value2");

    //set left location
    cbo.Left = 10;
    //set default top location
    int top = 5;
    //if this form contains more then 0 combo boxes, get last combo box Top value and increase it with 5.
    if (this.Controls.OfType<ComboBox>().Count() > 0)
        top = this.Controls.OfType<ComboBox>().Last().Top + 5;
    //set top value to new combo
    cbo.Top = top;
    //add it to forms control collection
    this.Controls.Add(cbo);
}
```

Comment: While the answer is valid, but it's better to use `FlowLayoutPanel` or `TableLayoutPanel`.

Comment: @RezaAghaei you're right, but it's hard to say what OP really needs. This answer is good as proof of concept, but OP will probably have to adapt this answer to his/hers needs